# How to remove the line from a link?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am trying to make my `<h1>` element a link.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<a href="site.html">
    <h1 id="logo" class="lobsterfont" style="margin-top: -10px;">
        Kusko Enterprise
    </h1>
</a>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&display=swap');

#logo a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#logo a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#logo a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#logo a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Instead of removing the line after I run the code, the line under the link is permanent instead.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Insert the style tag with the style="text-decoration:none" attribute in the  tag, so that your code looks similar to the following code:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none" href="http://Example.app.Com">nonunderlinedhyperlink</a>
```

Comment: Not my downvote but inline styles should be avoided unless **really** necessary

Answer (score 1):

In your .css file, you are targeting `#logo a:link` element, while your `a` element is outside `#logo`. You should either target `a` directly:

```css
a:link, a:href, a:focus, a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

or make `<h1 />` outer in your HTML:

```html
<h1 id="logo" class="lobsterfont" style="margin-top: -10px;"><a href="site.html">Kusko Enterprise</a></h1>
```

The latter used to be preferred, since headers are block elements and links are inline - but I am not sure if it is still the case.

Comment: As of HTML5 `hx` tags are valid inside `a` tags

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn more about [CSS Combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators). Your current CSS is targeting an `a` within an element with `id=logo`.

If you really want the `h1` in an `a` tag give the `a` tag the id instead.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&display=swap');
#logo:link,
#logo:visited,
#logo:hover,
#logo:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*Target h1 in an element with id=logo*/
#logo h1 {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="site.html" id="logo">
  <h1 class="lobsterfont">Kusko Enterprise</h1>
</a>
```